# How to delete a table before it SQL queries the data in Oracle APEX

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle-apex

So I have 3 tables/interactive grids in a page, and depending on the parameters being passed to that website, I only show 1 table and delete the other two. The problem is that the deletion happens after all 3 tables are made, so it is slow. Is there a way to delete these tables before they query anything, and only have 1 table query and show? Thank you

Comment: Let me get this straight. Are you creating an "admin" type tool that manages databases? Why are you creating/deleting tables at runtime? Also, unless the tables have a lot of data, deleting them should be pretty fast.

Comment: I have 3 tables in a page for a database table. Insert, Delete, and Update. Depending on the user and its privileges, it will get rid of the tables it doesn't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit confusing, but you can have a `Before Header` PL/SQL process to run whatever you want and it will run "before" showing anything on your page.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Does this mean the tables will be deleted before it queries the data?

Comment: Yep. I don't know what you're trying to do, but if you want to have "temporary tables" in your application I'd recommend having a look into APEX collections. This story of deleting/querying tables doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: I have 3 tables in a page for a database table. Insert, Delete, and Update. Depending on the user and its privileges, it will get rid of the tables it doesn't have access to.